# Webdav authentication performance / alternatives

Tags: iis, version-control, webdav

I am trying to find out how suitable Webdav is for a product by the company i am working at.

Our needs seem to exceed what Webdav has to offer and i'm trying to find out if my theory is correct and if so how we could work around it.

I am using the Webdav-package which you can install through the "add/remove windows features"-dialog.

The problem is that we want to be able to set permissions for each file and since we can access and change authoring-rules by code this is more or less possible.

Authoring-rules seem to apply to folders and not individual files but this could be worked around by giving each file it's own folder (although it's a bit ugly).

To me this solution seems very inefficient mainly because the authoring-rules are all placed in a list which means that for all file-requests the server has to loop through the entire list which gets larger for every file added to the server.

My thought is that we could build some kind of "proxy" that checks permissions in a more efficient way and if the user has permission to access the file we just forward the request to the webdav-server.

This might also be inefficient though since we have to have an application managing the connection between the user and the Webdav-server but at least the inefficiency isn't exponential.

**I guess this leads to the questions:**

Is Webdav at all suitable for more complex permissions?

Is there some part of Webdav that i have missed which solves this problem?

If so, would it be better to go with the internal solution or should we do an external solution?

If not Webdav, is there a better solution? (We want all the nice file-locking, version-control and office-integration stuff)

Answer (score 0):

use an HttpModule to apply your authorization rules.

`system.webServer/modules` has an attribute `runManagedModulesForWebDavRequests`
(!not the same as `runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests`)

Answer (score -1):

1. Forget about IIS
2. Forget about pure WebDAV
3. Build|get Apache+mod_svn
4. Use path-based authorization in SVN, which can enable (if needed) rules on per-file basis

Comment: IIS is required.
We have an entire business system developed in .Net Web-forms which over one hundred customers already use.
We don't want to have more than one web-server.
Basically we need something which works in IIS with Microsoft technologies such as C#, .Net, MSSql, Web-forms and MVC.

Comment: @DOOMDUDEMX - "We don't want to have more than one web-server" it's your (wrong, IMNSHO) choice. DEV-Apache as repository-server **only** is cheap but power solution

Comment: The goal is to maintain a "quick-deployable" solution so that the upgrade-procedure on hundreds of customers goes smoothly.
To add an entire other web-server (which introduces a lot of testing and research to make sure there are no security-issues by the way) to the solution is nothing close to smooth.
If we wanted to add another large package to the server we could just use sharepoint(overkill) since it has everything we need except for the smooth deployment.
Does DEV-Apache even have support for integration with Microsoft office by the way?(I can't find any information about it)

Comment: @DOOMDUDEMX - I'm sorry, but SCMs in common and Deploy-Tools are **different**, only slightly related things. You deploy **files** (objects), regardless of the nature of their appearance

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding me (or i'm misunderstanding you).
I'm **not** trying to use Webdav as a deploy-tool.
We have a deployment-procedure but we need the solution (which is more or less an intranet) to handle documents better.
Webdav, Sharepoint or even DEV-Apache would be used for handling documents on the intranet.
The problem is that Sharepoint and DEV-Apache are not lightweight enough.

Comment: @DOOMDUDEMX - OK, really lightweight SCM (**without** WebDAV only) - Subversion over `svnserve`. My p. 3 become "Configure repository with svnserve access-method"

Comment: @DOOMDUDEMX -- what did you go with? I have a very similar problem to yours.

Comment: @Tigran As of now, the project is on hold so i haven't really gone with anything yet.